# How to relate fields in Odoo 11 CE

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, journal

I added a custom field in "account.payment" model, I also added it in "account.move.line" model (aka: Journal Item).

The value of the custom field is entered from account.payment and since the journal items are generated from a payment creation  I want to do the following:

```
If account.move.line.id is created by account.payment.id    
    let account.move.line.custom_field = account.payment.custom_field
```

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You have to find in account.move.line that represent the relation(foreign_key) with account.payment, let says *payment_id*, this field allows you to access to account.payment model, and for your case you just need to do:

```
field_in_account_move_line = payment_id.field_in_account_payment
```

I hope this answer can be helpful for you.